# Symfony Form Collections: How to prevent duplicate INSERT on EntityManager->flush()?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have the following data model:

`MainEntity.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_type=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MainEntity
{
  // $id, etc...

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(
   *   targetEntity="App\Entity\RelationEntity",
   *   mappedBy="mainEntity",
   *   cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"},
   *   orphanRemoval=true
   * )
   */
  protected Collection $sideRelations;

  // getSideRelations(), setSideRelations($relations), addSideRelation($sideRelation), removeSideRelation($sideRelation)...
}
```

`RelationEntity.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *   name="main_side_relation",
 *   uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_pair", columns={"main_entity_id", "side_entity_id"})
 *   }
 * )
 */
class RelationEntity
{
  // $id, etc...

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
   */
  protected ?int $relationValue;
  
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MainEntity", inversedBy="sideRelations")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected MainEntity $mainEntity;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\SideEntity", inversedBy="mainRelations")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="side_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected SideEntity $sideEntity;

  // getRelationValue(), setRelationValue($relationValue), getMainEntity(), setMainEntity($mainEntity), getSideEntity(), setSideEntity($sideEntity)...
}
```

`SideEntity.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SideEntity
{
   // $id, etc...
   
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(
    *   targetEntity="App\Entity\RelationEntity",
    *   mappedBy="sideEntity",
    *   cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"},
    *   orphanRemoval=true
    * )
    */
   protected Collection $mainRelations;

   // getMainRelations(), setMainRelations($mainRelations), addMainRelation($mainRelation), removeMainRelation($mainRelation)...
```

I have existing Symfony form classes which I extended to fit the data model.

`RelationEntityType.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

class RelationEntityType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
   {
      $builder
        ->add('relationValue', HiddenType::class)
        ->add('mainEntity', HiddenType::class)
        ->add('sideEntity', HiddenType::class)
      ;
      // Add Transformers to switch between Entity and database ID for input value
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver): void
   {
      $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => RelationEntity::class]);
   }
}
```

`MainEntityType.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

class MainEntityType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
   {
      // ...
      $builder->add('sideRelations', CollectionType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'entry_type' => RelationEntity::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'delete_empty' => true
      ]);
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver): void
   {
      $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => MainEntity::class]);
   }
}
```

Submission works not as intended, as by using `by_reference` I explicitely remove and re-add existing unchanged collection entries, but when omitting the option it happens implicitly.

In both cases, `UnitOfWork` is filled with insertion queries for the already existing collection entries (and throws errors due to the unique constraint). I don't want that.

Symfony's [form collection configuration docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) doesn't yield valuable information on how to prevent collections from becoming "dirty" although their entries have technically not been changed.

How exactly do I avoid overwriting unchanged existing collection entries?

(If necessary, I can provide the remaining code for an MWE)

Comment: It should not reimport existing entry, it should update them at worst. Question: you have a ManyToMany relationship between MainEntity and SideEntity. Why would you declare RelationEntity? Do you store specific data on the join table?

Comment: Yes, there is another field I store on `RelationEntity`, else I would've used `ManyToMany` relations. I'll update the source codes.

Comment: @FlorentCardot And I would be fine with existing entries being updated, however both using and omitting `by_reference` creates INSERT queries in the `UnitOfWork`. I've seen workarounds (e.g. with listeners on Doctrine events) but I'm assuming there is a sorta "clean" way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Well, I used those collection form for oneToMany relation (even oneToMany imbricated into another) and i had no problem with it. Not sur about  manyToOne, not even sur it is possible on this way. Here is the detailled tutorial i followed to achieve it: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/embedded-form-collection